# How to update value in VecDeque?

Tags: rust, deque

I want to store value in a `VecDeque` and after it updates the value:

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn main() {
    let mut v = VecDeque::new();
    let mut str1 = String::from("Hello");
    
    v.push_back(str1);
    
    let str = String::from(" World");
    str1.push_str(&str);
}
```

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `str1`
  --> src/main.rs:10:5
   |
5  |     let mut str1 = String::from("Hello");
   |         -------- move occurs because `str1` has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
6  |     
7  |     v.push_back(str1);
   |                 ---- value moved here
...
10 |     str1.push_str(&str);
   |     ^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

How can I add item to collection and after it update this item?

Comment: Relevant method: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html#method.back_mut

Comment: @E_net4theKindDownvoter yep, thanks, it's working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My working example:

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn main() {
    let mut v = VecDeque::new();
    let mut str1 = String::from("Hello");
    v.push_back(str1);

    let mut str2 = String::from(" World");

    match v.back_mut() {
        Some(value) => value.push_str(&str2),
        None => println!("Error")
    }

    match v.back() {
        Some(value) => println!("{}", value),
        None => println!("Error2")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `back_mut`

```
v.back_mut().unwrap().push_str(&str);
```

or just store reference in the deque

```
v.push_back(&mut str1);
```